# PHP empty $_Files after Form POST

Tags: php, forms, post

I ran Into a problem Uploading Files from Input Forms to PHP:

As my Project is quite bug here is a striped down version of the code:

**HTML:**

```
<form id="uploadform" action="upload_files.php" method="post" encrypte="multipart/form-data">
    <input id="data" type="file" name="data">
    <input id="button" type="submit" value="upload">
</form>
```

**PHP:**

```
if(isset($_FILES['data']) && $_FILES['data']['size'] > 0){
    $data = $_FILES['data'];
};

echo json_encode($_POST);

echo $data;

echo json_encode($_FILES);
```

the echo results are:

```
{"data":"upload_test.txt"}
Notice: Undefined variable: data
[]
```

so as i have checked the php.ini file for

```
 file_uploads = On
```

and my test file is mere 8 bytes I don't know why **$_Files** is empty

I use PHP v 5.5.11 and XAMPP v 1.8.3

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` Place a `print_r($_FILES)` or `var_dump($_FILES)` in the PHP page which receives the form submission. Fill out your form, submit and look closely at the data that gets printed to the screen. Familiarize yourself with how form data is posted to scripts, including what gets passed and what doesn't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the problem:

```
encrypte="multipart/form-data"
```

change it to :

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

Comment: gosh i hate it what that happens. many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Change `encrypte="multipart/form-data"` to `enctype='multipart/form-data'`